# App_Code folder to dll in vs2013

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013, app-code

We have a superbly old web service on our production server that I applied very small updates to.  All that is in the project is

```
App_Code folder
     IService.cs
     Service.cs
Bin folder
     a few other dll's
Service.svc
web.config
```

All i've done is make a few changes to `Service.cs`.  On the server, the structure is:

```
Bin folder
    App_Code.dll
    other dll's
PrecompiledApp.config
Service.svc
Web.config
```

All I really want is to swap out that App_Code dll.  Using ILSpy, I confirmed it just contains those two .cs files.  However, when I build/publish/anything the app in VS2013, I cannot get it to create the App_Code.dll that I need.  I've been researching this the most of the day and haven't found a solution.  Clearly I'm not understanding how these old services work.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it.  When you go to the publish screen, go to Settings -> File Publish Options -> precompile during publishing.

Don't do like I did and overturn your desk and threaten to hulk smash your coworkers in anger.

Comment: Thanks. On the good side, I learned that Lucy from accounts can do that Black Widow lullaby thing.